# Playwright: authentication data is not being passed to the context from the state file

Tags: typescript, playwright

I wrote a function that registers and authenticates a user, and then saves the storgeState data to a state.json file.
I call it before each test - the data is written to the file, but when I call the method using the session data from the state.json file, I get a 401 error.

API: https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/4012288/TzK2bEa8

FUNCTION:

```
import { request } from "@playwright/test";
import { API_URL} from "../utils/constants"

export const getRequest = async () =>
    request.newContext({
    baseURL: API_URL,
    storageState: 'state.json'
});

export function randomString(length) {
    let result = '';
    const characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    const charactersLength = characters.length;
    let counter = 0;
    while (counter \< length) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() \* charactersLength));
    counter += 1;
    }
    return result;
}

export async function createUser(){

let request = await getRequest();

const randomName = `test${randomString(5)}`;
const randomLastName = `test${randomString(5)}`;
const randomEmail = `${randomString(5)}@${randomString(3)}.com`;
const randomPassword = `${randomString(8)}`;

const body = {
    firstName: randomName,
    lastName: randomLastName,
    email: randomEmail,
    password: randomPassword
}

const response = await request.post(
    '/users',
    {
        data: body,
    }
);

const bodyLogin = {
    email: randomEmail,
    password: randomPassword
    }

    const responseLogin = await request.post(
        '/users/login',
        {
            data:bodyLogin
        }
    )
await request.storageState({ path: 'state.json' });

}
```

TEST:

```
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';
import { getRequest } from '../../common/user';
import { randomString } from '../../common/user';
import { createUser } from '../../common/user';

test.beforeEach(async() =\> {
await createUser();
})

test('Should create a user', async () =\> {
let request = await getRequest();

const response = await request.get('/contacts');
const answer = response.body();
await expect(response.status()).toEqual(200)
});
```

If a token is specified in the headers, the request returns with a 200 status code:

```
const response = await request.get('/contacts', {
  headers: {
      Authorization: "eyJhbGciOiJIU"
    }
});
```

However, if it is taken from a file, I still receive a 401 error.

Answer (score 0):

You should add 'use' property with path to storageState file somewhere in you project. The most easy way to do it in your case is to put the following line before your test (after beforeEach section):

```
test.use({ storageState: 'state.json' });
```

Also you can add the same parameter in playwright config file in project section. More info can be found here: https://playwright.dev/docs/auth#basic-shared-account-in-all-tests